# Groupby and remove with condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
Group_name  Event   colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
Group1  1   1   1   1   0
Group1  2   2   2   4   2
Group1  3   2   2   4   2
Group2  1   8   8   8   0
Group3  1   2   2   2   0
Group3  2   2   2   2   0
Group4  1   2   2   5   3
Group4  2   2   2   2   0
```

And I wanted to only keep `GroupNumber` that corrspond to the folowing set of filter:

I keep a Group only if the `colomn4 values is =0` , otherwise I remove the group from the tab.

So I should get:

```
Group_name  Event   colomn1 colomn2 colomn3 colomn4
Group2  1   8   8   8   0
Group3  1   2   2   2   0
Group3  2   2   2   2   0
```

Have you an idea to do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for get groups if all values matched condition by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
df1 = df[df['colomn4'].eq(0).groupby(df['Group_name']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
  Group_name  Event  colomn1  colomn2  colomn3  colomn4
3     Group2      1        8        8        8        0
4     Group3      1        2        2        2        0
5     Group3      2        2        2        2        0
```

Alternative is get all groups with no `0` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverting mask by `~`:

```
df = df[~df['Group_name'].isin(df.loc[df['colomn4'].ne(0), 'Group_name'])]
print (df)
  Group_name  Event  colomn1  colomn2  colomn3  colomn4
3     Group2      1        8        8        8        0
4     Group3      1        2        2        2        0
5     Group3      2        2        2        2        0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @jezrael

Comment: And what is the equivalent if instead of .eq(0) I would like .sup(2) (everything > 2)?

Comment: @chippycentra - use `gt` for `>` or `lt` for `<` - [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)
[`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)